# Azure Stream Analytics query language get value by key from array of key value pairs

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to extract a specific value from an array property in the Stream Analytics query language.

My data looks as follows:

```
"context": {
    "custom": {
        "dimensions": [{
            "MacAddress": "ma"
        },
        {
            "IpAddress": "ipaddr"
        }]
    }
```

}

I am trying to obtain a result that has "MacAddress", "IpAddress" as column titles and "ma", "ipaddr" as rows.

I am currently achieving this with this query:

```
SELECT
    GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(MySource.context.custom.dimensions, 0), 'MacAddress') AS MacAddress,
    GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(MySource.context.custom.dimensions, 1), 'IpAddress') AS IpAddress,
```

I am trying to use CROSS APPLY but so far no luck. Below the CROSS APPLY query:

```
SELECT
    flat.ArrayValue.MacAddress as MacAddress,
    flat.ArrayValue.IpAddress as IpAddress
FROM
  [ffapi-track-events] as MySource
  CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(MySource.context.custom.dimensions) as flat
```

This one produces two rows instead of one:

```
MacAddress, IpAddress
ma        ,
          , ipaddr
```

so I'm missing precisely the flattening when writing it like that.

I would like to bypass hardcoding the index 0 as it's not guaranteed that MacAddress won't switch places with "IpAddress"... So I need something like FindElementInArray by condition, or some means to join with the dimensions array.

Is there such thing?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, were you able to get a solution? Please share if you do. I have exactly the same problem. Thanks!!

Comment: Unfortunately I ended up using the solution I mentioned in the question, hardcoding the index. This was more than an year ago so hopefully the language has evolved in the meantime and you will be able to avoid doing this.

Comment: one way to escape hardcoding the indexes is to create a UDF function and manipulate your custom dimentions `UDF.GetEventField(dimensions, 'field')'`
combine this with a WITH statement to create temporary tables and you should have a good manageable query